# Jetpack Compose 52 x 90 matrix is loading very slow

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning jetpack compose. When i make 90 rows each with 52 boxes inside, it takes 4-5 seconds for the screen to load. Can you give me an alternative for a faster way? Just a few words to suggest an idea will be enough, i will look it up after that. Any idea, suggestion is appreciated, thank you.

```
Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(25.dp, 65.dp, 25.dp, 35.dp)
        ) {

            for (year in 0 until 90) {

                Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                    for (week in 0 until 52) {

                        if (week == 0) {

                            if (year % 5 == 0) {
                                Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                                    Text(
                                        "${year}",
                                        fontSize = 5.sp,
                                        fontWeight = Bold,
                                        textAlign = TextAlign.Start
                                    )
                                }
                            } else {
                                Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                                    Text(" ")
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            val color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground

                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .weight(1f)
                                    .border(
                                        BorderStroke(
                                            1.dp,
                                            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                                        )
                                    )
                                    .background(color = color)
                            ) {
                                Text(" ")
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Are you testing performance in release mode with all optimizations applied? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance